# Visual Studio Code, Inline Folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, directory

How do I revert the folder stucture shown in the image below: "pages/multitour_pages/...".
I want it to revert back to the normal collapsing folders.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried renaming the folder using (f2) or right click -> rename

Comment: I have tried that yes, but thank you though